# $\Omega^0_c \to \Sigma^+ K^-K^- \pi^+$ Feynman diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, baryons

How can I work out the Feynman diagram for the [decay process](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2007/listings/s047.pdf), $\Omega^0_c \to \Sigma^+ K^-K^- \pi^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by identifying the constituents of each particle. The charmed baryon $\Omega^0_c$ is $ssc$, that is, two strange quarks and a charm quark. The sigma baryon $\Sigma^+$ is $uus$, the kaon $K^-$ is $s\bar u$ and the pion is $u\bar d.$ Thus, you know the initial and final particles in your diagram.

You can now use the [Feynman rules](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213) of the Standard Model to work out the interactions to include, which are allowed. In some cases, processes may be mediated by the weak or electromagnetic interaction; either can be used for a diagram, though one will usually be more probable.

To check which is in a particular case more probable, you will need to check the branching ratios from the Particle Data Group.

Thanks to anna v for the useful link to [quark flavour transformations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html); you can use these to see which interactions to pick in order to get the right flavours in the final state.

Just a minor caveat; this will not be *the* Feynman diagram for the process. Remember this is all at tree level, and you could consider arbitrary numbers of loops as well though the dominant contribution I believe for this process is at tree level.

Comment: This link would help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html

Comment: I think I figuered out a quite probable way it could have happened, the charm Quark turns into a strange one and comes with the other two together to form the Omega-, and the charm Quark addmits a W+ boson, wich turns into a pion+ (up, antidown). Thanks for the help and answer if you see a flaw in that.